# How to prove that the only non-empty connected components in a set $S$ are singletons

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am just beginning my study in topology and I am struggling with proving a theorem:

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ Consider the set $S = \{ 0 \} \cup \{1/n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \}$ equipped with subspace topology in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $S$ has singletons as its only non-empty connected components for each element in $S$.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$ I tried to show that every singleton in $S$ is open in $S$ by subspace topology, and I showed that every $\{ \frac{1}{n} \}$ is open when $n \geq 1$.

$\textbf{My question:}$ I wasn't able to show $\{ 0 \}$ is open $S$ by subspace topology.

So can somebody give some hint for my question here, or give another method to prove this theorem. Thanks very much!

Comment: Which textbook is it from ?

Comment: Hi, sorry that we don't use textbook but only use the handouts written by the instructor. And this is why I have to send this to Math StackExchange.

Comment: You should get the Definitions for the terms used here , then you can check whether the Question itself is valid & then try the Proof. To me , the Question seems "weird" , though I might be totally wrong there. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Connected_components for Ideas !

Comment: You weren't able to show $\{0\}$ is open in the subspace topology because that isn't true.  Nonetheless, it is still a component - components need not be open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components are the maximal connected subsets of $S$. That is to say, a component is connected and is not contained in a strictly larger connected component.

Each singleton subset of $S$ is a connected set.

Suppose $x \in C$ with $C\subset S$ and suppose $C$ is connected. If $C$ is not a singleton, then at least one of the points is non zero, and we can quickly contradict the assumption that $C$ is connected. Hence $C$ is a singleton.

Comment: Thanks very much for your hints!